R ggplot() plot whole dataframe and sort by median
My aim is to make a plot like that:

I don't want relative imporantces, I just want to plot each column in my dataframe as a boxplot and sort them by median. I don't have groups or anything else I want to plot by.
It works with the normal boxplot() function. But how can I do that with ggplot()?
And how is it possible to sort the boxplot by median if I do not have anything else to reorder by?
I can not give you my dataset, because it is not availble to the public. The dataframe is like the iris dataset but without the column "Species" etc. I only have the SepalLegthCm, SepalWidthcm etc.:


Reshape your data to long format and then recode your "grouping" variable to a factor variable based on the median. This second step of fct_reorder could be done either within the ggplot call or before via a mutate:
library(tidyverse)

iris |> 
  select(-Species) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) |>
  #mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, value, .fun = median, .desc =TRUE)) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(name, value, .fun = median, .desc = TRUE), y = value))



That worked, thank you so much.
Do you know as well how to color now by self defined groups? I have 35 columns and want to make 3 groups and give every group a color.
For example with the iris dataset: Sepal Length = orange, Petal Length and Width = green and SepalWidth = red.

Create a new variable in this reshaped dataset where you combine the 35 "names" into 3 colour groups and refer to that color column when adding a colour to your plot. There are countless websites/tutorials on how to colour a ggplot.

Somehow I can't do it. I know how to color the ggplot(), but it does not work to add a variable with the desired groups.
I wanted to do it like that:
mutate(iris_group = case_when(       str_detect(name, "Sepal.Length") ~ "category1",       str_detect(name, "Petal.Length", "Sepal.Width") ~ "category2",       str_detect(name, "Petal.Width") ~ "category3",       TRUE ~ ""))
But how do I need to write the value in category 2 - "Petal.Length" and "Sepal.Width", in brackets, with another separator etc.?

str_detect(name, "Petal.Length|Sepal.Width") ~ "category2"
